# How to read Excel worksheets into datatables

Tags: excel, datatable, ms-office, global

I'm trying to solve this problem that I have in my application.

I'm doing a add-in excel for excel, and I've never done it before.

What I need to to do is open an excel file in excel and then I need to use `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook` 
to access the workbook and retrieve the data from 4 worksheets into a datatable.

No connections with constrings, I have to work directly with the open book.
I've been working on this and getting nowhere.
Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it on my own, which is great.

Comment: Maybe you would like to share your solution with the community then? Even though it hasn't been helpful on that one...